# conect multiple buttons to same function with different parameters

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to create multiple buttons by a for loop.
Pressing on the buttons call same function but transfer a different parameters.

```
def someFunction(self):
      buttons = [None] * 8
      for i in range(8):
            buttons[i] = QPushButton(self)
            buttons[i].clicked.connect(self.function(i))

def function(self, i):
        print(i)
```

I expect the output of buttons[i] to be i but the output always 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self) 
        self.someFunction()

    def someFunction(self):
#        buttons = [None] * 8
        for i in range(8):
            button = QPushButton("Button {}".format(i), self)
            button.clicked.connect(lambda ch, i=i: self.function(i))      # < ---
            self.layout.addWidget(button)

    def function(self, i):
        print(i)

if __name__ == '__main__':        
    app = QApplication([])
    mainapp = MainWindow()
    mainapp.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you could add a few words on what you have been doing to solve the issue.